# Reading String With NSUserDefaults not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm using iOS9 SDK, and I'm trying to read a string using :

```
NSString *savedID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"ID"];
```

I saved it using :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[myPeripheral.identifier UUIDString] forKey:@"ID"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

The problem is that the property `savedID` has a `nil` value.

When I execute the ligne bellow in the consol, I get the value I saved :

```
po [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"ID"];
```

> PS : The value I saved is : 73BAE46D-3A74-E7F4-05F7-EFCB6AACC20C

I also tried to use `objectForKey`, but I still got the same result.

Any Idea?

Comment: I guess you read the value right after having written it, which is not reliable because writing to user defaults works asynchronously.

Comment: No, I closed the App, then I tried to read the value.

Comment: The value is saved, but I cannot store it on a NSString, when I checked Its class It was NSCFString, can this be the source of the problem?

Comment: no, `NSCFString` is the internal class signature. Your code is correct.

Comment: but Its not working :(

Comment: Your code seems OK. I would change key to something other than ID, and if that didn't work, I'd make sure you are not saving anything to it other than the line you posted.

Comment: Just tried this, I changed the ID to "AirIdentifier", I m sure I m saving the String, 'cause I can check this on the consol

Comment: The problem is when I affect the value to the NSString

Comment: @vadian Your first comment is completely wrong. Changes to `NSUserDefaults` can be read immediately and it is reliable. It's all in memory. It is the persisting do disk that happens occasionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was debugging on a device, I tried to execute the App without debug and it worked :p

Thank you every one.